# Validate unique cell value in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, cells

I have a `grid` with a `textfield` column. I want to make sure user enters unique data into the cell. But if I use `validator` event, it validates as soon as the cell gets clicked.

I want to validate it after the cell has finished editing. I have tried `validateOnChange`, it doesn't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validateOnChange is not an event, rather it's a config option.
Set it to false in your textfield config.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to validate it after the cell has finished editing,you can use **blur** event listener:
[blur](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-blur)

Other way is using regex and regexText.